# Need alternative get_posts function for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I need to get Related Posts for custom post type. This works only for post. But shows nothing for custom post type as wp_get_post_categories($id) returns nothing.

```
$related = get_posts( array( 'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($id), 'numberposts' => $post_num, 'post__not_in' => array($id) ) );
```

I changed the above code. But still get nothing.

```
$category = get_the_terms( $id, 'cases' );
    $cat = array(); 
    if($category){
        $cat[] = $category->term_id;
    }
    $related = get_posts( array( 'category__in' => $cat, 'numberposts' => $post_num, 'post__not_in' => array($id) ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

The default value for the parameter `post_type` is `post`. To get posts from your custom post type specify the `post_type` parameter accordingly. More information about the usage of [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) is available at the related codex page.

Comment: I added post_type but do not help me. get_posts do not work for custom post type.

Comment: No idea, why it isn't working for you, must be something else, but I can assure you, `get_posts()` does work with custom post types. @user3351236